# 59:18: Error: The method 'isDuplicateColumnError' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseException'

Tags: flutter

I'm experiencing this error message on flutter_cache_manager 2.1.0 which doesn't allow me to execute the app
has anyone experienced this issue before?

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_cache_manager-2.1.0/lib/src/storage/cache_info_repositories/cache_object_provider.dart:59:18: Error: The method 'isDuplicateColumnError' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseException'.
 - 'DatabaseException' is from 'package:sqflite/src/exception.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.1.7+2/lib/src/exception.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'isDuplicateColumnError'.


 - 'DatabaseException' is from 'package:sqflite/src/exception.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.1.7+2/lib/src/exception.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'isDuplicateColumnError'.
          if (!e.isDuplicateColumnError(CacheObject.columnLength)) rethrow;
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

sqflite 1.1.7 looks outdated. Can you try `flutter pub upgrade`?

Comment: I'm not using FLutter 2 yet. THe weird thing is that in other projects I have no problem compiling at all, even adding this version of cache manager